# What is point-to-point channel described in stream socket?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, datagram

From this post [What's the difference between streams and datagrams in network programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688855/whats-the-difference-between-streams-and-datagrams-in-network-programming), the 2nd answer says:

> Stream Socket:
>   Dedicated & point-to-point channel between server and client.
>   ...
>   Datagram Socket:
>   No dedicated & point-to-point channel between server and client.
>   ...

What is the point-to-point channel described here ? Why stream socket is point to point while datagram is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stream socket provides a connection between two endpoints. Point to point channel means usually a TCP connection. A connection is established before user data is sent and the connection is released later. The connection has always two end points and data can be transferred between these end points.

A datagram socket can be used for communication with multiple peers. It is usually used for communication over UDP. A datagram socket is not bound to any remote peer and it is possible to receive data from multiple peers through a single datagram socket. It is even possible to send data to multiple peers through a datagram socket when destination address is a broadcast or multicast address.